# How to filter a Flex DataGrid with numbers in column?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have wrote a function for filtering DataGrid columns with text within. But now i need to filter a column with numbers. I can´t solve it to get this function work.

```
private function refilterArticle():void {
        filter.text = StringUtil.trim(filter.text.toLowerCase());
        if( filter.text.length == 0)
        produkteListe.lastResult.produkte.produkt.filterFunction = null;
        else
        produkteListe.lastResult.produkte.produkt.filterFunction = filterArticle;                        
        produkteListe.lastResult.produkte.produkt.refresh();
        }

        private function filterArticle( e:Object):Boolean {
        //if( String(e.usernachname).toLowerCase() == filter.text.toLowerCase() )
        if( String(e.artikelnummer).toLowerCase().indexOf( filter.text) != -1)
        return true;      
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Is the filter fucction invoked? ```filter.text``` and ```e.artikelnummer``` are Numbers?

Comment: Should ```articleNumber:1221``` and ```filter.text:22``` also match?

Answer (score 0):

filter is the name of the textfiled an e.artikelnummer is coming from mysql/php. This function above works fine, but only if i search within a text column. I need it for column with numbers. I am very new to Flex and i am not sure if i need something like toLowerCase and so on.